# Manipulate error for duplicate entries - MySQL and PHP

Tags: php, mysql, error-handling, duplicates

I have set up a MySQL table multiple columns, one of which acts as a unique index. This column corresponds to one of my form inputs so that I can prevent duplicate row entries.

Being new to PHP, my question is: when the MySQL duplicate entries error is called, what would be the most succinct way of manipulating it so that I can display a custom message or return the user to the original form?

I'm guessing that `mysql_errno` and `header();` would be the way to go but I'm struggling to understand how.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't want regular users to see the mysql_error that is displayed, so a custom message is preferred here. When you're using a mysql_query with an insert or update statement it will return true on success and false otherwise.

You could do something like this to solve it:

```
$query = "query goes here";
if(mysql_query($query)) {
    echo "Success!";
} else {
    echo "Data not submitted. Please try again.";
}
```

You could of course modify this so that the user is redirected somewhere upon success or failure. If you want to use the `header` function to redirect a user make sure that there is not output on the page before the function is called.

Comment: This definitely makes more sense than my `mysql_errno` suggestion. Would `SELECT` have any benefits over `INSERT`?

Comment: It all depends on what you want to do. If you want to insert new information into the table then you use the `INSERT` statement. If you want to retrieve information from the database, you use the `SELECT` statement. If you want to update information in a table you use the `UPDATE` statement. [Here's](http://www.tizag.com/mysqlTutorial/) a tutorial that you can use to learn mysql.

Comment: Okay, that's great. You've been ridiculously helpful. Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 questions actually.

1. How to check for the duplicate error.
2. How to show *whatever* error, not just particular one to the user.

For the first, I'd rather use SELECT than INSERT. Check uniqueness with SELECT and then raise an error.

For the second, follow POST/Redirect/GET patter: do not redirect anything anywhere, but just include your form and populate it with entered values.

Finally, I hope you're not going to identify your records based on this user-supplied unique field

Comment: For the first part, I'm guessing you're referring to something like `SELECT * FROM WHERE....`?